# How to dynamically rotate multiple points around a central point

Tags: javascript, math

I'd like to be able to rotate multiple points around a central point. I'm trying to make it so it's sorta "dynamic", as in, when a point is destroyed, the other points update so it's still evenly circling the central point.

Basically for some experimental canvas thingy. I've tried lots of combinations of the math, to no avail

```
var spinner = undefined;
var angle = 0;
var z = 0;
function spinUser(){
  if(spinner) clearInterval(spinner);
  spinner = setInterval(function(){
    angle = z*(Math.PI/180);
    for(var i = 0; i < pointArray.length; i++){
      let px = central.x + 3 * Math.cos(angle+i*(pointArray.length-points)) * 9 / 16;
      let py = central.y + 3 * Math.sin(angle+i*(pointArray.length-points));
      updatePos(px,py,i);
    }
    z += 2.5;
    if(z >= 360) z = 0;
  },50);
}
```

3 = radius
2.5 = speed

Say there should be 5 points, excluding the central point. It should do math, taking the current number of points and subtracting(?) by how many there should be, and updating the points' position like so.

Sorry if this question isn't as good as it should be, I'm kinda new to this question thing.

Comment: Are you looking for the angle of the `i`-th point given `n` total points? That would be simply `angle + i * 360 / n`.

Comment: something like that...i'm looking to evenly space points based on how many points there are. as in, 4 points is like, the points form a square, right? 3 points is a triangle, 2 points is they're across from eachother, etc.

Comment: Then use the formula I posted.